# Order by In Linq Where Some dates are hypen

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to use `orderBy` on a `Datatable` using linq and sort according to a `String` column "BirthDate".

```vb
dt.AsEnumerable.OrderBy(Function(x) CDate(x.Item("BirthDate").ToString)).CopyToDataTable()
```

But Some Date Values contains hyphens and throwing error.

What could i do if i want the hypen values at last or first.
I need both answers for different scenarios.
Thanks

Comment: Save dates as Date type ;)

Comment: @Fabio i cant do that the dates are coming from excel, the format is fixed.

Comment: _the format is fixed_ - then parse dates with fixed format with `DateTime.ParseExact` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Fabio i tried CDate but it is not working

Comment: Can you give an example of the dates?

Comment: @Magnus {"12-01-2019","10-31-1992","-","10-10-2015"}

Comment: @Fabio didn't say CDate. He said DataTime.ParseExact. Di you try that?

Comment: @Fabio I did Try but error persists

Comment: What `Date` value you want to get when converting `"-"` to date?

Comment: @Fabio , i need syntax of how to handle empty rows or "-" , where it expect to be a date value..... inside a query function

Comment: What date value you expect when value is "-" or empty?

Comment: @Fabio I know it can not be parsed what i need is syntax to handle this situation like if condition in order by so that these rows come at last... i hope you get that i dont want to parse these values

Comment: Try to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` then [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Fabio If i use Tryparse it does not perform order by. Allthe values containing hypen come at last or first but ones with parsable dates values are not sorted

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that could be applied to your situation.  It does assume that the date field is a string, and that the field is a date.

```
    'sample data
    Dim d() As String = {"1/1/2018", "1-2-18", "Jan 3, 2018", "4 Jan 2018"}

    Dim ie As IEnumerable

    ie = From s In d
            Select s Order By Date.Parse(s) Descending
```

edit:
example that skips invalid dates

```
    'sample data
    Dim d() As String = {"1/1/2018", "1-2-18", "", "Jan 3, 2018", "4 Jan 2018"}

    Dim ie As IEnumerable

    'this will skip invalid dates
    ie = From s In d
            Where Date.TryParse(s, Nothing)
            Select s Order By Date.Parse(s) Descending
```

Comment: How will you handle if some values are hypen or blanks like {"1/1/2018", "1-2-18","-", "Jan 3, 2018","" ,"4 Jan 2018"}

Comment: @AnkitKwar - edited post to show skipping of invalid dates

Comment: This is what worked in this case -> I had to loop over the data table one more time and replace all the hypen with some reference date that i know would come at last when sorted.

Comment: @AnkitKwar - what?  Hyphens are valid date part separators.  Did you try the code I posted?

Comment: The platform i am using is UiPath,  your code somehow does not work there, somehow the syntax is not supported. In my case the only separator was '/'. SO removing that and re placing the blank string with ref date (like 01/01/0001) was doable. and that worked for  me.